# Spark Structured Streaming : Not showing output in console

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Output console just displaying the schema and not contents of CSV file..
My CSV file format is :

```
/home/user/Downloads/temp_stream
user@ubuntuvm:~/Downloads/temp_stream$ `InvoiceNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,InvoiceDate,UnitPrice,CustomerID,Country
536365,85123A,WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,6,12/1/2010 8:26,2.55,17850,United Kingdom
```

`

Following is the code in intellij:
package Streaming

```
object StructuredStreaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark Structured Streaming").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    //want to see only error logs
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("Error")


val retailDataSchema = new StructType()
  .add( name = "InvoiceNo", IntegerType)
  .add(name = "StockCode", IntegerType)
  .add(name = "Description", StringType)
  .add(name = "Quantity", IntegerType)
  .add(name = "InvoiceDate", TimestampType)
  .add(name = "UnitPrice", DoubleType)
  .add(name = "CustomerId", IntegerType)
  .add(name = "Country", StringType)


val streamingData = spark
  .readStream
  //.option("header","true")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
  .schema(retailDataSchema)
  //.option("inferSchema","true")
  .csv("/home/user/Downloads/temp_stream")
//we want to see transactions happened in UK
val filteredData = streamingData.filter("Country = 'United Kingdom'")

   //output sink
val query = filteredData.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .queryName("filterByCountry") // any name for query
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

}`

```
Output:
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|Description|Quantity|InvoiceDate|UnitPrice|CustomerId|Country|
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: try writing the rows of the csv file only when the streaming application is already running. It might only process new messages and not the ones that are already there

Comment: Still not working... same thing no output

Comment: try a second file via an mv or cp

Comment: is it a directory or a file?

Comment: "/home/user/Downloads/temp_stream" is directory  and it has one file initially Retail1.csv  having following data for example `InvoiceNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,InvoiceDate,UnitPrice,CustomerID,Country
536365,85123A,WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,6,12/1/2010 8:26,2.55,17850,United Kingdom`

Comment: Try pushing a second file

Comment: Batch: 1
`-------------------------------------------
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|Description|Quantity|InvoiceDate|UnitPrice|CustomerID|Country|
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+`

Comment: File content is `user@ubuntuvm:~/Downloads/temp_stream$ cat sample2.csv
InvoiceNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,InvoiceDate,UnitPrice,CustomerID,Country
536365,85123A,WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,6,12/1/2010 8:26,2.55,17850,United Kingdom
536365,71053,WHITE METAL LANTERN,6,12/1/2010 8:26,3.39,17850,United Kingdom
user@ubuntuvm:~/Downloads/temp_stream$ 
`